# AppEngine - JDO - a single call to a batch get query.execute(...) raises several datastore_v3.Get calls

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I have implemented an AppEngine Java app. It runs just fine - except that i'm having way too many datastore read operations.

So I installed the `appstats` tool to analyze it. It showed up that on a single request i am doing in one point of my code:

```
Query query = persistenceManager.newQuery(Info.class,
                    ":keys.contains(key)");
List<Info> storedInfos = (List<Info>) query.execute(keys);
```

That single call to `execute(...)` results in multiple `datastore_v3.Get` calls. I get this stack trace multiple times:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder:297 makeAsyncCall()
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy:184 makeAsyncCall()
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper:59 makeAsyncCall()
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl:351 doBatchGetBySize()
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl:400 doBatchGetByEntityGroups()
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl:292 get()
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl:87 get()
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService:90 get()
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery:374 executeBatchGetQuery()
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery:278 performExecute()
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JDOQLQuery:164 performExecute()
org.datanucleus.store.query.Query:1791 executeQuery()
org.datanucleus.store.query.Query:1667 executeWithArray()
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery:243 execute()
de.goddchen.appengine.app.InfosServlet:78 doPost()
```

It is even calling `executeBatchGetQuery` so why is this issued multiple times?

I have already tried out some datastore/persistencemanager settings but none helped :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably seeing keys being broken into groups and the query being executing asynchronously. How many keys are you querying for?

Comment: ~100 keys are getting executed in ~20 queries. But how do i control that behaviour?